# Programmatically creating Bootstrap tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create some Bootstrap 3.3.5 tabs with jQuery 2.1.4 and I'm not getting too far.  I can only get the tab headers to appear and not the actual content.  I've made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3qmvxxs1/2/) with the relevant code.

```html
<header class="navbar navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="navigtion"></ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="tab-content" id="tabulator"></div>
</div>
```

```js
var categories = {
    general: {
        label: "General",
        options: [{
            key: "opt1",
            label: "Option 1",
            desc: "The first option",
            def: true
        }, {
            key: "opt2",
            label: "Option 2",
            desc: "The second option",
            def: true
        }]
    },
    advanced: {
        label: "Advanced",
        options: [{
            key: "opt3",
            label: "Option 3",
            desc: "The third option",
            def: false
        }]
    }
};
$(function () {
    $.each(categories, function (i, v) {
        $("#navigtion").append("<li><a data-toggle='tab' data-target='" + i + "'>" + this.label + "</a></li>");
        $("#tabulator").append("<div class='tab-pane' id='" + i + "'/>");
        $.each(this.options, function (i2, v2) {
            $("#" + i).append("<div class='checkbox'><label><input type='checkbox' id='" + this.key + "' title='" + this.desc + "'>" + this.label + "</label></div>");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I get a "General" and "Advanced" tab.  What is the desired result?

Comment: Sorry about that, I'll update the OP. There is also actual content in each of the tabs, but it just isn't activating.

Comment: Try replacing with this:    $("#navigation").append("<li><a data-toggle='tab' data-target='#" + i + "'>" + this.label + "</a></li>");

Comment: Also you have navigtion in some spots and navigation in others

Comment: I'm going to cry, thank you.  If you post this as an answer I can mark you as the solver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You have a typo:  (navigation in some places, navigtion in others)

2)  Add a # to the one line:

```
$("#navigation").append("<li><a data-toggle='tab'
data-target='#" + i + "'>" + this.label + "</a></li>");
```